# Связанные таблицы в Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, relation

Здравствуйте у меня возникла проблема.
Имеются 2 связаные таблицы users и rules.
Также есть 2 модели:
`User`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'rule_id'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function rule()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Rule', 'id');
    }

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }
}
```

`Rule`

```
class Rule extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rules';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public static function getRules()
    {
        $rules = DB::table('rules')
            ->select('id', 'title')
            ->get();
        return $rules;
    }
}
```

`UserController`

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    protected $users;

    public function __construct(User $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->users->with(['rule' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'title');
        }])->get();
        dd($users);
    }  
}
```

В таблице `users` имеется 3 записи но связывается только одна запись остальные идут без связи, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Покажите еще схему таблиц и как вы создаёте эти модели

Comment: @xEdelweiss я выложил код ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внешний ключ содержится в `users`, поэтому получается, что `User` принадлежит (`belongsTo`) к `Rule`. И наоборот - `Rule` имеет (`hasOne`) одного `User`.

Laravel предполагает, что имена ключей соответствуют названиям моделей (`rule_id` для `Rule`), поэтому указывать их не обязательно.

Получается как-то так:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public function rule()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Rule');
    }

    // ...
}    

class Rule extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('rule_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('rule_id')->references('id')->on('rules');
    });
}  

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('rules', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title', 50);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Создаю через миграции